# How to import git submodules into NetBeans 8.1?

Tags: git, netbeans, git-submodules

I have a NetBeans project which is controlled by a Git repository. I am using one GitHub project as a dependency ; when I began the project I was new to Git so I just cloned the dependency, took the source code and put it as a package as if it was my own.

Now that I'm a little bit more experienced with Git, I'd like to have the dependency as a git submodule, so I can use it, easily update it, and have everything in one place so end-users (my project is an API) won't need to clone the dependency as a side project.

I discovered submodules from [the SVN guide](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) ; so I made a new branch, deleted the dependency package and initialized the submodule, then opened NetBeans, but NetBeans just doesn't see it.

I was expecting the submodule to show up in some place like the library list, but it surely isn't there.

After research on the NetBeans forums, I have noticed that they never mention submodules in the documentation.

So, is it possible to use submodules in NetBeans ? I am not searching for anything complicated, just keeping my project and the dependency separated. I am not planning to do anything other than to compile the dependency (ie. no modifications), but I'd rather keep this doable if possible. And if this is not possible under NetBeans, what is the closest to achieve this goal ? (I have heard about Maven but have no knowledge whatsoever of what it is)

Related links : [The project I'm talking about (GitHub)](https://github.com/CLOVIS-AI/Telegram), [the dependency (GitHub)](https://github.com/ralfstx/minimal-json)

[EDIT]
After checking, my problem does not come from the git command line (the git submodule is initialized as it should in the project folder), but rather seems to be a NetBeans configuration issue. Based on the error ("package ... not found" on every import), I guess that NetBeans just doesn't know where to find the submodule's source. I have tried to add the submodule manually to the libraries by right-clicking the 'libraries' folder in the IDE then 'add project/folder'. I have tried this for various folders in the submodule, but none seem to let NetBeans find the source (it is in there though). [Here is the link to the dependency, maybe there's something specific about how the folders are laid down, I don't know. (from GitHub)](https://github.com/ralfstx/minimal-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of NetBeans 8.2, git submodules as supported natively. In NetBeans 8.1, they were not, here is how I managed to use them :

My problem was not with the git command line ; you can find information about that here : [submodule tutorial on the SVN guide](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules)

After checking that the submodule was initialized as it was supposed to be, I followed these steps :

1. Open NetBeans
2. In the "project" tab, right-click on the project, select "properties"
3. Go to the "sources" tab, select "add folder"
4. Select the src/ folder in the submodule

This doesn't make the submodule a library : instead, NetBeans thinks it's part of your code. In my case, this is good enough, but I want to point it out.

Also, expect all your previous imports to be broken (package name may have changed).

This solution feels like a hack so I would gladly have someone explain how to make NetBeans recognize the submodule as a library, but in the meanwhile I think this can still help.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use submodules with NetBeans, even though the git commands won't work directly from the NetBeans GUI: see [bug 271489](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=271489).

At least, changes should be detected ([bug 207067](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=207067))

However, start without NetBeans:

- in your working tree (on your disk), with your new branch checked out, add your submodule (that is declare the URL of the other Git repo which has the sources of your dependency)
  Don't forget to add, commit and push from your main repo.

Then clone that repo again (`git clone -b yourBranch --recursive`): that will clone your main repo and initialize the submodules content, all in one command.

Open NetBeans and check that everything is visible.

Comment: I have done that, the command-line doesn't show any errors; but in NetBeans the submodule does not show in the "library" folder nor anywhere I checked, and every import is broken in NetBeans ("package minimaljson doesn't exists"). Is there any configuration in the project's files needed ?

Comment: @CLOVIS "the command-line doesn't show any errors": but is your submodule subfolder correctly filled out after the `git clone -b yourBranch --recursive`?

Comment: Yes, there is a folder at the root of the project, containing the full GitHub data of the submodule, which makes me think NetBeans is just lacking the path to it ? (I'm running NetBeans 8.1)

Comment: By right-clicking on "libraries" then "add project/folder" and adding the submodule, I have access to its code - though it's full of errors because the files there do not 'see' each other, if I add the imports myself they go away, but my main project still can't see the package's library

Comment: @CLOVIS OK, so that seems to be a NetBeans project configuration issue, and less a Git submodule issue.

Comment: What do you think I should do now ?

Comment: Simplify, meaning not worrying about Git or submodule, but just try to make those set of files work properly in a netbeans project.